# Open Graph Beta: Adding units to actions or objects for publish_action?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, distance, facebook-opengraph

I've been reviewing the [Open Graph Beta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/) docs, and I'm interested in how to add measurement units to action or object properties. The classic example is "User Ran a Route". Is there a way I can say that Route is '5 km' and '3.1 miles'? Further, I'd like to choose the right property to [aggregate as one big number](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/) for the user. User A may work in 'miles' and User B may work in 'km'.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have locale aware units for the Open Graph. Even on Facebook we don't change status updates from "I ran 5km" to "I ran 3mi".

The best I can recommend is to attach two properties onto your Object. Distance and Distance (in miles). Then build 2 aggregations, one for the Distance and one for the Distance in miles.

Then when a user runs a route, you only have to publish one property based on their locale and only 1 aggregation will show up.

You have to be careful to be consistent for the same user otherwise they'll end up with 2 aggregations fracturing their distance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this system:

if locale US:

```
<meta property="CANVASNAME:distance" content="3.0" /> 
<meta property="CANVASNAME:distance:units" content="miles" />
```

if locale DE, FR, ...:

```
<meta property="CANVASNAME:distance" content="5.0" /> 
<meta property="CANVASNAME:distance:units" content="km" />
```